# Write own work-connection to gnosis contracts without using gnosis services

Tags: gnosis-safe

Please help!

1. We want to write scripts that will be connected to the gnosis contracts 1.3.0 version.
2. This script will be executed on the network that you do not support in the UI. As our network still does not have code verifications. I'll show you all the examples on goerly test network. In addition to that, we have already deployed all needed smart contracts for the test net and mainnet. safe-deployments (https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/pull/274) and here https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/blob/eb34caa969e510e963654fd0c062d612ab35ece9/artifacts/1230/deployment.json
3. I need to sign the transactions and then execute them. using these scripts. Example: 4 owners, 2 thresholds.
4. **The problem is** in signatures concatenation (I think). I was looking in the code base for each helpful piece of lib in Safe Global for the latest versions.
5. I tried to understand the logic of signing to concatenate signatures
   properly. I wrote down the logic for the contract creation, but I still have issues 25 or 26 during sending a transaction with execution. **My Example of Deployed proxy**: 0x75584bBFE5B54A8cE75Ff2f6263cE64e748E2cbF
   **TX example for execution script bellow**: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x39c918a7f25a38168a4e54b41a6cfa46a0230c821eee096bb3725321905e29e7

```
ACCOUNT_1(from DEPLOYER_PK) = 0xfd5602704b331a9C98Bb05F1887b402450E4616D
ACCOUNT_2(from OWNER_2_PK) = 0x984b44631560114e5846225501c806EF2929d982
ACCOUNT_3 = 0x17e51697e66085Ab72380EF6554391d798876Bd9
ACCOUNT_4 = 0xD419175f4eba712cf2a2dfedE5DA8E30EdE972d2
```

1. To deploy the wallet we used `await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig });` and types `import { SafeAccountConfig, SafeFactory } from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";` and deployment works good

The code of a signing and execution script for 4 owners, 2 thresholds. The script signs transferring money FROM a safe wallet to a certain address. The Native coin was already sent directly to the proxy contract

```
import { task } from "hardhat/config";
import SafeApiKit from "@safe-global/api-kit";

import {
  EthersAdapter,
  SafeAccountConfig,
  SafeFactory,
} from "@safe-global/protocol-kit";
import {
  SafeTransactionDataPartial,
  OperationType,
} from "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types";
import Safe from "@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/Safe";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import {
  executeTx,
  buildSignatureBytes,
  safeApproveHash,
  buildSafeTransaction,
} from "@gnosis.pm/safe-contracts";

const {
  ACCOUNT_1,
  ACCOUNT_2,
  ACCOUNT_3,
  ACCOUNT_4,
  ACCOUNT_5,
  MULTI_SEND_ADDRESS,
  SAFE_MASTER_COPY_ADDRESS,
  SAFE_PROXY_FACTORY_ADDRESS,
  DEPLOYER_PK,
  OWNER_2_PK,
} = process.env;

task(
  "exec",
  "First signer proposes a transaction, can be used only for native tokens",
)
  .addParam(
    "treasury",
    "The address of the safe wallet/treasury smart contract address",
  )
  // .addParam("amount", "The amount of tokens")
  // .addParam("receiver", "The address that uses for receiving native coins")
  .setAction(async (args, hre) => {
    if (
      !MULTI_SEND_ADDRESS &&
      !SAFE_MASTER_COPY_ADDRESS &&
      !SAFE_PROXY_FACTORY_ADDRESS &&
      !ACCOUNT_1 &&
      !ACCOUNT_2 &&
      !ACCOUNT_3 &&
      !ACCOUNT_4 &&
      !ACCOUNT_5
    )
      throw new Error("Check that addresses in .env file was set properly");
const provider = hre.ethers.provider;
    const signer1 = new ethers.Wallet(DEPLOYER_PK!, provider);
    const signer2 = new ethers.Wallet(OWNER_2_PK!, provider);
    const balance = await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(args.treasury);
    console.log(signer1.address);
    console.log(signer2.address);

    const safeTransactionData: SafeTransactionDataPartial = {
      to: "0xC9C0CD4C0db99f7292CC7BfB678a001C4132021f",
      data: "0x",
      value: "123",
    };

    const safeProxy = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
      "GnosisSafeProxy",
      args.treasury,
    );
    // to make nonce() function executable, import abi from L2 contract for proxy
    const safe = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
      "GnosisSafeL2",
      args.treasury,
    );

    const tx = buildSafeTransaction({
      to: "0xC9C0CD4C0db99f7292CC7BfB678a001C4132021f",
      value: 123,
      nonce: await safe.nonce(),
      operation: 0,
      gasPrice: 0,
      safeTxGas: 0,
    });
    const additionalInfo = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
      ["uint256", "address", "uint256"],
      [tx.nonce, signer1.address, 1],
    );
    const signatures = [
      await safeApproveHash(signer1, safe, tx, true),
      await safeApproveHash(signer2, safe, tx, true),
    ];
    const signatureBytes = buildSignatureBytes(signatures).toLowerCase();
    // await safe.methods
    //   ['execTransaction(address,uint256,bytes,uint8,uint256,uint256,uint256,address,address,bytes'](
    //     tx.to,
    //     tx.value,
    //     tx.data,
    //     tx.operation,
    //     tx.safeTxGas,
    //     tx.baseGas,
    //     tx.gasPrice,
    //     tx.gasToken,
    //     tx.refundReceiver,
    //     signatureBytes,
    //     { from: signer2, gasLimit: 180000 },
    //   );

    await safe.connect(signer2).execTransaction(tx.to,
        tx.value,
        tx.data,
        tx.operation,
        tx.safeTxGas,
        tx.baseGas,
        tx.gasPrice,
        tx.gasToken,
        tx.refundReceiver,
        signatureBytes,
        {gasLimit: 180000 },
      );
    // console.log(tx, additionalInfo, signatures, signatureBytes);
  });
```